# Minecraft won't let me download or play it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

When I tried to get on a Minecraft server it said:

> Unauthenticated by minecraft.net

So I went and tried to re-download it. When I finished the process and it was just installing the launcher said:

> Cannot be downloaded due to corruption, please try again.

I did it and it still won't work. Please help me, I really enjoy this game.

Comment: Are you using a pirated or hacked version (getting the game for free)?

Answer (score 3):

If your game is actually corrupted than I recommend the following:

- On Mac, go to your finder, then library, then application support. Then delete the folder called 'Minecraft' Also delete all Minecraft apps and DMG's on your computer. Re-Download the app from the *official Minecraft website*!
- On Windows, type %appdata% in your file explorer and so the same thing as above.

If you are using cracked or free version of Minecraft then it just won't work.